# PHP Redirect Not Working When In A Nested IF Statement

Tags: php, if-statement, redirect

I've looked at several of the "PHP redirect not working ......" posts, but I haven't had any luck figuring out what is going on with my problem.

The code below always goes to `teacherActivity_2.php` even though the 2nd if passes and should redirect to `teacherActivity_3_shadowT.php`. If I comment out the  `teacherActivity_2.php`, the page redirects (as expected) to `teacherActivity_3_shadowT.php`. I think I'm missing some obscure rule that I should know but don't. Any ideas?

**Why does this redirect to `teacherActivity_2.php` instead of `teacherActivity_3_shadowT.php`?**

```
if($test == 'yes') {
  if($_SESSION['wblReporting']['activity'] == 'shadowT'){
  header('Location: /app/do_cte-wbl/forms/teacherActivity_3_shadowT.php');
  }
header('Location: /app/do_cte-wbl/forms/teacherActivity_2.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to add die(); after this line header('Location: /app/do_cte-wbl/forms/teacherActivity_3_shadowT.php');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if($test == 'yes') {
  if($_SESSION['wblReporting']['activity'] == 'shadowT'){
    header('Location: /app/do_cte-wbl/forms/teacherActivity_3_shadowT.php');
    die();
  } else {
    header('Location: /app/do_cte-wbl/forms/teacherActivity_2.php');
    die();
  }
}
```

This worked no matter how many elseifs I used.